# org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. while initializing android driver in emulator

Tags: java, android, selenium

While initilizing android driver in emulator device produced sessionNotCreatedException. Am new for android automation. Anyone please help?.

Nov 18, 2016 5:35:25 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
Nov 18, 2016 5:35:25 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to straight W3C remote end connection
Nov 18, 2016 5:35:25 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to original OSS JSON Wire Protocol.
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'c7b525d', time: '2016-09-01 14:52:30 -0700'
System info: host: 'thangaraj', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.19.0-25-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:618)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:40)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:242)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:129)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:36)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:114)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:132)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:92)
    at initialize.Setup.initialize(Setup.java:230)
    at script.ScriptRunner.setup(ScriptRunner.java:67)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:100)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:515)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:216)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:143)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:307)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:270)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1284)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1209)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1124)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1096)
    at runTestNG.RunTestng.runTestNG(RunTestng.java:19)
    at runner.Runner.main(Runner.java:11)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{app=/home/ionixx/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.apk, appPackage=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, appActivity=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, noReset=true, browserName=, maxSession=10, platformName=Android, version=4.4, deviceName=Nexus1}], required capabilities = null
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'c7b525d', time: '2016-09-01 14:52:30 -0700'
System info: host: 'thangaraj', ip: '127.0.1.1', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.19.0-25-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
Driver info: driver.version: AndroidDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:597)

Answer (score 0):

Please check the packages that you included selenium 2.53.1 source and 2.53.1 jar. and include all the jar files present in the lib folder after extracting selenium 2.53.1.
-use testng.xml file to set the flow of the test case.

Authorship: Imran Ansari, colleague of mine.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by just changing the app path

```
 capabilities.setCapability("app", <<apk file path>>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Working after changing the correct App path(apk path).